# jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery

I have a datepicker that is already set up, how can I access the datepicker instance for use in another part of my javascript. I plan to use the click event of an element, get the date of the datepicke and initiate a query via a url.

Thanks guys,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#datepicker').hide();


<?php echo "$('#eventlist').load('events/findevent/" . $date . "');"; ?>
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function(selecteddate){
                $('#eventlist').load('events/findevent/'+selecteddate);
            },
            beforeShowDay: function(date,inst){
                var found = false;
                var i = 0;
                while(!found && (i<valid.length)){
                    found = (!(date>valid[i] || date<valid[i]));
                    i++;
                }
                return [found,'',''];
            },
            onChangeMonthYear: function(year,month,inst){
                $('#eventlist').load('events/findbymonth/'+"0"+month);
            }
        });
    });
```

In the Html I simply have a div tag with the id as datepicker. In addition to the date picker, I have 4 buttons next and prev for the month and date. when a user clicks the next for either of the fields the the date will shift to the next available date. I have all the dates in a javascript array so the I am trying to use the date picker instance in the click function of a given button, get the date and set the new date. That way the actions will be called to update other fields with respect to the presently selected date. Any suggestions will greately appreaciated.
thanks.

Comment: A little information about what datepicker you're using would probably give us more chances of helping you out. Basicly, we need to know how do you call the datepicker inside of HTML..

Answer (score 1):

Pass the the events `beforeShow(input, inst)` and `onChangeMonthYear(year, month, inst)` as the datepicker options:

```
$('#el').datepicker({
    beforeShow:function(input, inst){},
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst){}
});
```

The inst param is the datepicker element that will be created.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery datepicker (I'm assuming this is the one you're using) has an [onSelect callback](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect); you probably want to use that instead of trying to read the date out of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the getDate method:

```
<input type="text" id="theDate" name="theDate>

var theDate = $('#theDate').datepicker('getDate');
```